# SQL JOIN TWO TABLES WITH GROUP BY

Tags: sql, join

I am new to the world of databases etc. A developer who made my shop's POS took a large sum of money and would no longer answer me. I need to report my receivables as end end of the quarter. Please help with this query in access. I tried left join and it works fine when I join only the purchases, but not purchases and payments.

TABLES:

```
CUSTOMERSTABLE:
CUSTOMERID**********NAME

PURCHASESTABLE:
SALEID**********CUSTOMERID**********AMOUN******TDATE

PAYMENTSTABLE:
PAYMENTSID**********customerid*********amount******TDATE
```

The result should show all the customerids (with available transations or not), the total amount of purchases for each, the total amount of payments for each, the outstanding amount (net of the two), it should only consider transactions before a given TDATE

Comment: Show what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cust.customerid, Sum(purch.Amount_charged) AS totalPurchases, Sum(pay.Payment_Made) AS SumOfPayment_Made
FROM (cust INNER JOIN pay ON cust.customerid = pay.Account_Id) INNER JOIN purch ON cust.customerid = purch.Account_Id
WHERE ((([purch].[TDATE]) Between '4/6/2015' And '5/18/2015'))
GROUP BY cust.customerid;
```

Comment: He has some conditions at the end with TDATE

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried but I got an error in "from clause". I attached my database here https://www.dropbox.com/s/e6of17s1rw7t94q/test.accdb?dl=0 maybe you can take a look. I am not lazy or looking for you to do my work, but I have been really trying this all day. I know very little apart from pressing run query...

Comment: I've edited the answer based on your uploaded table structure for a sample date. you can change the fields and/or values in the query according to your needs.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately it did not product the desired result. Infact I reduce the database to a total of 2 records per table. When I run the query only one record from the customer table is being returned, while there should be 2 with their corresponding date. I attached the sample. I hope you have the kindness to finish what you started, cause I sure cant :( https://www.dropbox.com/s/b5y1pmsy7899igb/test%20fail.accdb?dl=0

Comment: Do I did it by writing two queries and then running a query on those two queries. Would be great if someone can understand how to join them into one :(

SELECT Account_Master.ID, Sum(fees_charged.Amount_Charged) AS [Sum Of Amount_Charged]
FROM Account_Master LEFT JOIN fees_charged ON Account_Master.id = fees_charged.account_id
GROUP BY Account_Master.ID;

Comment: SELECT Account_Master.ID, Sum(paymentmade.payment_made) AS [Sum Of payment made]
FROM Account_Master LEFT JOIN paymentmade ON Account_Master.id =paymentmade.account_id
GROUP BY Account_Master.ID;

Comment: SELECT DISTINCTROW [Account_Master Query2].ID, Sum([Account_Master Query2].[Sum Of Amount_Charged]) AS [Sum Of Sum Of Amount_Charged], Sum([Account_Master Query2 Query].[Sum Of payment made]) AS [Sum Of Sum Of payment made]
FROM [Account_Master Query2 Query] INNER JOIN ([Account_Master Query2] INNER JOIN Account_Master ON [Account_Master Query2].[ID] = Account_Master.[ID]) ON [Account_Master Query2 Query].[ID] = Account_Master.[ID]
GROUP BY [Account_Master Query2].ID;